# Regex for matching all instances of a word except a specific superstring containing that word

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a regex that would match all instances of a word except a specific string that contains that word.

For example, I would like to match all instances of ***`stack`*** in the following sentence except ***`stack.overflow`*** (*because it is followed by **`.overflow`***) and replace ***`stack`*** with ***`STACK`***

> This is a stack of pages on stack overflow. Sometimes also referred to
>   as stack.overflow.com

After performing a replace operation, the above sentence should look like:

> This is a STACK of pages on STACK overflow. Sometimes also referred to
>   as stack.overflow.com

**Edit:**

To clarify some confusion, I wanted to match all strings that contained `stack` in all lowercase except a specific situation where `stack` was followed by `.overflow`. For example, the following sentence

> I stacked this stacking stack and re-stacked (stACked it again) but no 
>   stack.overflow but stacked.overflow and restacked.overflow

should be

> I STACKed this STACKing STACK and re-STACKed (stACked it again) but no 
>   stack.overflow but STACKed.overflow and reSTACKed.overflow

Comment: What do you want to do in the case of the word `stacks`?

Comment: `and replace stack with STACK`
Read the question, @moveaway00! :-P

Comment: It's not super clear if the OP wants to replace only instances of the word stack(separated by word boundaries, period included), or all instances of the 5 characters 'stack', even if they are sub-strings of larger words.

Comment: When you say "except **a specific** string that contains that word", do you mean all strings? What about "I stacked this stacking stack and re-stacked (stacked it again) but no stack.overflow or stacked.overflow or restacked.overflow". That wasn't a real sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead.

```
\bstack(?!\.overflow)
```

To make it case insensitive use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag.

C# sample code with a `Regex.Replace` where  the flag is replaced with an inline `(?i)`  option:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?i)\bstack(?!\.overflow)", "STACK");
```

Proof:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be a negative lookahead?

Comment: With positive lookahead, this is the opposite of what the OP asked for. See https://regex101.com/r/lE4kZ5/2 to see how this regex works with the supplied example.

Comment: Guys, it is not so easy answering using a mobile. Fixed.

Comment: \bstack(?!\.overflow) fits my needs perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. I am finally sitting at a desktop and posting a screenshot with proof.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("This is a stack of pages on stack overflow. Sometimes also referred to as stack.overflow.com"
    ,"stack(?!\.overflow)"
    ,"STACK")
```

This works for me. (excluding matches followed by ".overflow".)

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple : use lookarounds!
They match the begginning and end of a word.

```
(?<=\s|^)stack(?=\s|\.$)
```

I can't give you a demo of the whole thing as lookbehinds are not supported in Javascript, but see [here](http://regexr.com/#3atn4). You can then get your match, and replace it with `toUpper`.

**Explanation**

`(?<=\s|^)` Looks for a space or the beggining of the string before the word.

`(?=\s|\.$)` Looks for a space or a dot and the end of the string after the word.

Comment: Did you test your pattern? `(?=\s|.$)` means "a single white-space character OR any one character before the end (except new-lines)"

Comment: I did, but messed up while removing the escaping \. Thank you, @Kobi